# Keep the last 9 digits of an alphanumeric string in R

Tags: r

Please R-gurus, how can I keep the last 9 digits of an alphanumeric string
for e.g.

> LA XAN 000262999444
>   RA XAN 000263000507
>   WA XAN 000263268038
>   SA XAN 000263000464
>   000263000463
>   000263000476

I only want to get

> 262999444
>   263000507
>   263268038
>   263000464
>   263000463
>   263000476

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty easy in `stringr` because `sub_str` interprets negative indices as offsets from the end of the string.

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(xx, -9, -1)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the last 9 positions, you could just use `substr`:

```
substr(xx,nchar(xx) - 8,nchar(xx))
```

assuming that your character vector is stored in `xx`. Also, as Hadley notes below, `nchar` will return unexpected things if `xx` is a factor, not a character vector. His solution using `stringr` is definitely preferable.

Comment: But be careful your "string" isn't actually a factor, or you'll get very surprising results.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input is a vector named "strgs":

```
sub(".*(.........)$", "\\1", strgs)
#[1] "262999444" "263000507" "263268038" "263000464"

?sub
?regex
```

Comment: it seems not to work if the cell contains only the 9 nine digits. pls confirm

Comment: +1 But the modifier after the first period should be *, i.e. `.*` - this will return 0 or more matches.

Answer (score -3):

Not really sure which language you are looking for but here would be a c# implementation.

The logic would be something like :

```
    string s = "WA XAN 000263268038";
    s = s.Substring(s.Length - 10, 9);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: could this be executed in R? Thanks